# How to mount file from host to docker container on ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, dockerfile, amazon-ecs

I want to mount a file from my host-EC2 to a container which is running on ECS server. Every change that happens on the file that is on the Host, should be updated on the file in container.
What I have tried is as follows:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
volume /etc/nginx/conf.d
RUN ln -sf conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/
EXPOSE 80
```

Then pushed the image on ECR Repo and created task, added volume(source path:conf), mountpoint(/etc/nginx/conf.d) and created service to run the container. However every change that I do in the host server, dir: /conf/default.conf does not work on the container /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

I know there is docker run -v but as I'm using ECR, it runs the container itself through the setup.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion: In you build system, copy the file to S3, and then in your docker container, run a script on startup that copies the latest file back from S3 and mounts it.  Then you won't have to rebuild/redeploy your docker container constantly.